# Tried creating Active directory domain, upon restarting not able to login back to server

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain-controller

I saw a video on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4PhcnV8gSs&feature=g-hist) to create active directory domain on my server. I followed same steps and created group policy as shown in video. I do only have password that I entered while setting up active directory but forgot everything else.

Now upon restarting server, I am locked out and not able to login to server. I do not have physical access to server as it is hosted on GoDaddy's virtual dedicated server.

Any suggestions/solutions will be a big help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you have is the Directory Services Restore Mode password. This isn't going to help you.

What you need is the password of an administrator account on the server from before you promoted it. The local administrator account on that server is now the Domain Admin account for your domain. Use that. If you don't remember it, ask GoDaddy to reimage your machine and start over.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. You are right, I have Directory Services Restore Mode password. I was never given password of administrator as I was using Virtual dedicated server. I was given with user name as DOMAIN\USERNAME and XYZ as a password. Now which one is local administrator account? If I asks GoDaddy to reimage my machine, would this result in loosing all my data hosted on server?

Comment: If it wasn't a member of the domain before, it wouldn't be `domain\username` it would be `machine\username`. Use that username and password, except replace the machine name with the domain that you created. Really though, this is a site for professionals, so this is a bit off topic.

Comment: No, It wasn't a member of domain. Rather I was trying to create a domain on my server so that I could add my developer machines to this server. I think you are right it must be machine\username. The problem is I forgot what was the domain name that I created. Is there a way to get it?

Comment: Luckily, I was able to hit the right domain that I was expecting I must have created but still I am curious to know solution of my above comment. What if I wan't to restore this process i.e. remove active directory back

Comment: Honestly, there's no recovery procedure for forgetting what you named your domain and forgetting the names of your domain admin accounts. That's just bad form. This is why you document things and don't jump into Active Directory (or anything for that matter) if you don't understand it.

Comment: @MrDMarra: I agree for Production environment, experiments are not allowed. But person learns by making errors, and this gives a best leason.